# Ruby Validation failed on .create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am attempting to use a .create method but constantly getting back the error:

`Validation failed: Account can't be blank`

This is the code I am running to produce the error:

What could cause `.create!` to produce that error when it is apparent that `:account` is not blank?

Edit:

Here is some more info around my validations:

*It's worth noting that I the sample code in my initial post is not the complete script, but simple the code I am experiencing the error with. I define several other attributes inside that script but didn't want to put too much noise in this post.

Comment: can you post your `Test` validations and your `NewEntry` validations?

Comment: Can you post the code for your `newentry` class.  Also, make sure that if you have an `attr_accessible` definied for your `newentry` class that `:account` is in the list of accessible attributes

Comment: I added `Test` and `NewEntry` validations as well as changed my tag. I am using rails 3.2.14. Thanks for the help, @RobDiMarco `attr_accessible` is not defined in my `newentry` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are `validates_presence_of` on the `account_id` but you are passing in the `account`.  The error message says `Account` because when humanizing the field name, it drops the id.

You may want to try create with:

```
test.newentry.create!({
              :account_id => demo_account.id,
              :date => date
})
```

Comment: This was my suspicion as well, but no luck. I even tried passing `:account_id => 1` to make sure it wasn't blank, but I get the same error.

Comment: My apologies- I forgot to change the code throughout the rest of the loop. That works perfectly, thanks for the help!